# Solana web3 js keep gives Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'negative') while trying to confirm transaction

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, web3js, solana, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to sign a transaction with connected user's wallet, through phantom but I keep getting this error message

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'negative')

below is my transaction function

```
async SendTransaction(from,to){
        console.log(from);
        // const f  = JSON.stringify(from)
        // console.log(f);
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({
              fromPubkey: new PublicKey(from.publicKey),
              toPubkey: new PublicKey(to),
              lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 100,
            }),
          );
          let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")).blockhash;
          transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash
          transaction.feePayer = from

        
        //   Sign transaction, broadcast, and confirm
          const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
            connection,
            transaction,
            [from],
          );
          console.log(signature);
        return transaction
    },
```

Comment: You sure the issue is in this file? No `negative` here.

Comment: Have you checked that phantom is connected to a wallet?

Comment: I'm getting this too. Have you solved it?

Comment: See also https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/sendandconfirmtransaction-returns-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same issue.

In my case the problem  was with the value I was passing in as feePayer.
We need to be passsing a PublicKey object just like we do for toPubKey and fromPubKey in the SystemProgram.transfer method.
However I was passing in the publicKey string.
I, instead passed a PublicKey object ( new PublicKey(fromAddress) ) as the value for feePayer and it started working.

Please verify your feePayer value.